# Repeating transactions after a deadlock in InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I'm a little confused on how to handle deadlocks in innodb. Here's acommon scenario i've found online:

```
while (some deadlock condition)
{
    try {
        begin transaction
        query 1
        query 2 // let's assume this one failed with a deadlock
        ...
        query N
        commit
    }
    catch {
        make sure it's a deadlock AND
        rollback
    }   
}
```

- Question 1: So assuming **query 2** fails, shouldn't i simply reapeat that query instead of rolling back the entire transaction and only roll back after X attempts?
- Question 2: Could a simple select without any additional isolation instructions (i.e. SELECT * FROM table WHERE smth=smth) ever get into a deadlock?

Comment: I keep thinking the DB Engine should retry in some way as you suggest in question 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Answer 1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-error-handling.html):

> A transaction deadlock causes InnoDB to **roll back the entire transaction**. Retry the whole transaction when this happens.

Answer 2:

[No](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locks-set.html) if the transaction isolation level is lower than `SERIALIZABLE` (or if run outside of a transaction):

> `SELECT ... FROM` is a consistent read, reading a snapshot of the database and **setting no locks** unless the transaction isolation level is set to `SERIALIZABLE`.

Yes if `SERIALIZABLE`:

> For `SERIALIZABLE` level, the search sets shared next-key locks on the index records it encounters.

[Remember that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-deadlocks.html)

> Normally, you must write your applications so that they are always prepared to re-issue a transaction if it gets rolled back because of a deadlock.

A `SELECT` may also just time-out, waiting for a lock from another transaction (e.g. a table-lock).