# Deal with deadlocks in MySQL/InnoDB

Tags: mysql, jdbc, innodb

I'm benchmarking MySQL under different isolation levels.

For the case of SERIALIZABLE I frequently get this error: `"Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction at the client side"`.

Reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-deadlocks.html didn't help me much.

I have the following question:
What is the state of the database whenever I get the message ? Everything is frozen and the system expects from me to do something or my transaction has been already aborted and I just get informed about it ?

I'm using jdbc driver to connect to MySQL. Supposed my policy is to re-issue such failing transactions, do I need to call `connection.rollback()` or MySQL has already done that for me ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Repeating transactions after a deadlock in InnoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19700388/repeating-transactions-after-a-deadlock-in-innodb) - The offending transaction is fully rolled back, calling `connection.rollback()` would be superfluous (but would not pose a problem).

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a deadlock, MySQL will detect it and automatically roll back transactions as necessary to break the deadlock. It favors rolling back smaller transactions (affected rows).

If your transaction is rolled back, it is assumed that you will re-issue the transaction. MySQL does not do it for you.

When you receive such an alert, MySQL is not waiting on anything. It has already performed the rollback.